# Problema com MySQL Pool conections

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, node.js

Tenho essa classe que uso para criar a conexão:

```
class DbConnection {
  constructor() {
    this._con = undefined;
    this._pool = undefined;
  }

  _createPool(  database , user, password ) {
    this._pool =  mysql.createPool({
      connectionLimit: 100,
      host: "localhost",
      port: 3306,
      database: database,
      user: user,
      password: password
    });
  }

  async openConnection( req ) {
    this._createPool(req.database, req.user, req.password );

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err)
          reject( err );
        this._con = connection;
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  async beginTransaction() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.con.beginTransaction(err => {
        if (err) {
          this.con.rollback( () => this.con.release() );
          reject( err );
        }
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  get con() {
    return this._con;
  }

  close() {
    if (this.con)
      this.con.release();
  }
}
```

Esse é o controle:

```
class GenericCtrl {

  constructor( db, dao ) {
    this._db = db;
    this._dao = dao;
  }

  async buscar( req, res ) {
    req.assert( 'id', 'um id é necessário.' ).notEmpty().isInt().withMessage('Deve ser inteiro');

    if (req.validationErrors())
      return res.status( 400 ).json( { erros: req.validationErrors() } );

    try {
      await this._db.openConnection( req );
      let response = await this._dao.read( req.params.id  );

      res.status( 200 ).json( response );

    } catch (e) {
      res.status( 500 ).json( { erro: e.toString() } );

    } finally {
      this._db.close();
    }
  }

}
```

Esse é o DAO:

```
class GenericDao {

  constructor( db ) {
    this._db = db;
  }

  get con() {
    return this._db.con;
  }

  read( query, sql = undefined, inserts = undefined ) {

    sql = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?";
    inserts = [ 'Usuario', 'id', 23 ];

    sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);

    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
      this.con.query( sql, ( err, result ) => err ? reject( err ) : resolve( result ) );
    });
  }

}
```

Tem mais Código, apenas retirei o trecho que julgo necessário para a questão.

O código funciona, mas as vezes ele mostra um erro no `log` como a mensagem:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Connection already released

Não sei como faço para consertar isso. Alguém pode me ajudar?
Caso precise de mais detalhes eu atualizarei a pergunta. Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que como as chamadas são realizadas assincronamente, você pode criar uma nova conexão a cada requisição e, antes que a primeira seja finalizada, uma segunda pode ser iniciada. O caminho é você utilizar as variáveis e retornos dentro de um escopo definido ou utilizar usar diretamente a função `query` do `pool` (e em consequência "enxugar" bastante seu código).

> [**Pooling connections**](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections)
>
> Rather than creating and managing connections one-by-one, this module also provides built-in connection `pooling` using `mysql.createPool(config)`. [Read more about connection `pooling`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool).
>
> Create a pool and use it directly:
>
> ```
> var mysql = require('mysql');
> var pool  = mysql.createPool({
>   connectionLimit : 10,
>   host            : 'example.org',
>   user            : 'bob',
>   password        : 'secret',
>   database        : 'my_db'
> });
>
> pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
>   if (error) throw error;
>   console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
> });
> ```
>
> This is a shortcut for the `pool.getConnection() -> connection.query() -> connection.release()` code flow. Using `pool.getConnection()` is useful to share connection state for subsequent queries. This is because two calls to `pool.query()` may use two different connections and run in parallel.

Em tradução livre:

> Ao invés de criar e gerenciar conexões uma por uma, este módulo também provê um `pooling` de conexão embutido usando `mysql.createPool(config)`.  [Leia mais sobre `pooling` de conexão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool).
>
> Cria um pool e o usa diretamente:
>
> ```
> var mysql = require('mysql');
> var pool  = mysql.createPool({
>   connectionLimit : 10,
>   host            : 'example.org',
>   user            : 'bob',
>   password        : 'secret',
>   database        : 'my_db'
> });
>
> pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
>   if (error) throw error;
>   console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
> });
> ```
>
> Este é um atalho para o fluxo de código `pool.getConnection() -> connection.query() -> connection.release()`. Usar `pool.getConnection()` é útil para compartilhar o estado da conexão para as queries subsequentes. Isso é porque duas chamadas para o `pool.query()` podem usar duas conexões diferentes e executar em paralelo.

Então em resumo você pode remover todas as manipulações a variável `con` (inclusive a criação de uma nova conexão), adicionar um `get` para o `pool`, remover o `finally` do seu `controller` e mudar seu método `read` para:

```
// ...
read(query, sql, inserts) {

  sql = 'SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?';
  inserts = ['Usuario', 'id', 23];

  sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);

  return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
    this.pool.query( sql, ( err, result ) => err ? reject( err ) : resolve( result ) );
  });
}
// ...
```

Existem também algumas melhorias que você pode fazer com relação as promessas, usando `async` e `await` e simplificando seu código, mas não abordarei isso nesta resposta.